Python Polars issue with lazy evaluation
I have two dictionaries with keys string and values polars expresions.

factor_query_dict
currency_factor_query_dict

And I'm doing this:
factor_holdings = holdings.lazy().with_columns(
        [
            pl.coalesce(
                pl.when(polars_query).then(pl.lit(factor, dtype=pl.String))
                for factor, polars_query in factor_query_dict.items()
            ).alias("factor"),
            pl.coalesce(
                pl.when(polars_query).then(pl.lit(factor, dtype=pl.String))
                for factor, polars_query in currency_factor_query_dict.items()
            ).alias("currency_factor"),
        ]
    )

When I do .collect() the. first column is populated but the second is not.
The difference is when I avoid the lazy part both columns are populated.
What could be the reason?
I tried:

Try generating a minimum example but in that case it worked. The unique difference in the execution plan was that the strings literal in the expression where Utf8(bla) and in my case it where String(bla).
I tried casting the pl.lit with both dtype=pl.Utf8 and pl.String and the result is the same.
When printing the execution is says for example pl.col("A").is_in(Series) how can I see the values in the series?


It could be an optimizer bug. You can try disabling them to see if any are the cause e.g. .collect(comm_subexpr_elim=False) You can use .collect(no_optimization=True) to turn off all optimizations which could confirm if it is the optimizer.

fyi, pl.Utf8 is pl.String. I'm curious how Utf8 is appearing anywhere when it's been globally replaced by String in polars.

@jqurious both options .collect(comm_subexpr_elim=False) and .collect(no_optimization=True) generate the correct output

@BallpointBen maybe the difference was because in the container I have polars 0.20.6 and in my local env I have 0.19.18

So that would suggest it is a CSE issue. If you can manage to reproduce it - you can file a bug to get it fixed. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues

@jqurious I managed to reproduce it https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/16138 Thanks for your help
